# How to calculate the probability of $P((A\cap B)\cap C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that, $$\mathbb P(A∩B) = \mathbb P(A) * \mathbb P(B|A),$$ But I'm unsure if it works the same for $$\mathbb P(A∩B∩C).$$ Would that be calculated like this:$$\mathbb P(A) * \mathbb P(B|A) * \mathbb P(C|B) $$

Comment: No, it's $P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid A\cap B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we consider $C$, we know that both $A$ and $B$ are true, so we get:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B|A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)
$$
Indeed, by the law you mention we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B|A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)
=
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)
$$
and applying the same law once again, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)
=
\mathbb{P}(C \cap (A\cap B))
$$

The "trick" here is to write $A\cap B\cap C$ as $C \cap X$ where $X=A \cap B$, and using the conditional probability law you mention on $X\cap C$, first, and then on $A\cap B$.

Comment: I still have one question left. How would you calculate $$\mathbb P(C|A∩B),$$ without knowing $$\mathbb P(A∩B∩C)?$$

Comment: @Destyl It depends on what you actually know. It is the same of calculating $\mathbb P (C|X)$ without knowing $\mathbb P (C \cap X)$. Sometimes, in concrete cases, you just know that, assuming $X$ has happened, $C$ has a certain probability.